# NodeJS update user status dynamically with Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have this little issue. I have a service that has a Subscription option. When an item in the DataBase is modified (i.e. customer order), I want the customer to see the change in real-time.

Once the user logs in, he is automatically subscribed to his order's status (or several orders, as the case may be). When the status changes, the service sends a POST to a URL that I designate and when that is done, I want to change the client's order status, however I have no idea how to modify Angular's model in order to change what the user sees.

```
    module.exports = function (app) {
    app.route('/api/machine')
        .post(function (req, res) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
            return res.send("post returned " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
        })
};
```

At the moment, I get the updates from the Service and print them out, but how do I update the view as well?

Answer (score 0):

try use $watch() function.. when the value is modified, the view is updated.

```
$scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.data.myVar },
          function(newValue, oldValue) {
              document.getElementById("").innerHTML =
                  "" + newValue + "";
          }
         );
```

I dont know how you've constructed this project's structure, but if you're using a API, use http post to notify your front when changes are done.

the digest or watch, will make your controller do a function always the value has changed.

[Angular Digest,Watch and Apply docs.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)

i hope this helps.

cya.

Comment: I am aware of that functionality within Angular, my problem is setting values within that function from the NodeJS / Express REST API... :)